# Is it possible to "overload" an alias template depending on a constraint?

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++-concepts

Can we have an alias template that points to a type if a constraint is false, or to another type if that constraint is true ?

```cpp
template < class T >
using MyType = SomeType;

template < class T >
  requires SomeConstraint
using MyType = SomeOtherType;
```

I know doing it this way doesn't compile but is there a workaround ? Because I want to have some types in a class that are set to `void` if a constraint is not respected, or to something else if the constaint is respected without having to make the whole class require that constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, either by moving the alias into a class and partially specializing the class (and then aliasing the alias in the class from the outside), or for the case you are showing simpler:

```
template<typename T>
using MyType = std::conditional_t<requires{ requires SomeConstraint; }, 
                                  SomeOtherType, SomeType>;
```

Depending on what `SomeConstraint` is (I am assuming it to be a placeholder for something more complex than an identifier) probably also just

```
template<typename T>
using MyType = std::conditional_t<SomeConstraint, 
                                  SomeOtherType, SomeType>;
```

will be fine.

In either case this will require however that both `SomeOtherType` and `SomeType` are valid types (again assuming these are placeholders). It will not apply SFINAE to them. If that is not given you need to fall back to the class partial specialization method.

---

The class template partial specialization method:

```
template<typename T>   
struct MyTypeImpl {
    using type = SomeType;
};

template<typename T>
requires SomeConstraint
struct MyTypeImpl<T> {
    using type = SomeOtherType;
};

template<typename T>
using MyType = typename MyTypeImpl<T>::type;
```

Comment: Okay, so back to the beginning, I was looking for a SFINAE friendly way, but still thanks for your help, I will validate your answer

Comment: Yes I knew about the class template partial specialization method but I was looking for a simpler approach

Comment: @Fayeure There are variations of this method, but I don't think any would be really simpler (neither in length nor in comprehensibility).